# Get or convert Week of year to ISO week

Tags: vb.net

While trying to get the number of weeks in a year I tried this:

```
maxWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(New Date(t_year, 12, 31), 
          CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

Which didn't work well for my purpouse, but I noticed something weird. For 2014-12-31 it returned 53 and for 2015-01-01 it returned 1. For 2015-01-05 it returned 2. That means that the weeks 53 and 1 are smaller then 7 days!

I need the result to be [ISO Week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) compliant. I couldn't find online any examples of calendars following this same logic. Them all show the week 1 as from 2014-12-29 to 2015-01-04.

Comment: You are asking for `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek`. If you don't like the result, try the [other options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg Indeed I tried This other rules, but any returned 01 from the 29th of december, as I would expect [ISO week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). By what I see on the examples on this msdn page there is no rule compatible with what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original post does not mention you are looking for ISO week, which may have made what you want unclear.

The NET `GetWeekOfYear` using `FirstFourDayWeek` and `DayOfWeek.Monday` is *almost* like an ISO Week. The difference is that an ISO Week is always seven days.  Keep in mind that an ISO Date is not just a different format, but a different *calendar* complete with its own terms (like leap week).  Your default NET calandar on the other hand is Gregorian.

It is not hard to tweak a NET WOY to an ISO Week:

```
Public Shared Function GetISOWeekOfYear(dt As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim cal As Calendar = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar
    Dim d As DayOfWeek = cal.GetDayOfWeek(dt)

    If (d >= DayOfWeek.Monday) AndAlso (d <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday) Then
        dt = dt.AddDays(3)
    End If

    Return cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)

End Function
```

Simple tester for 12/31/xxxx:

```
For n As Integer = 1990 To 2016
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: week:{1}", n.ToString,
                      GetISOWeekOfYear(New DateTime(n, 12, 31)).ToString)
Next
```

Output of just the last few:

> 2005: week:52
>   2006: week:52
>   2007: week:1
>   2008: week:1
>   2009: week:53
>   2010: week:52
>   2011: week:52
>   2012: week:1
>   2013: week:1
>   2014: week:1
>   2015: week:53
>   2016: week:52

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! You are right, I should have mentioned in the post that I was looking for the ISO week.

Comment: Unbelievable how crazy it is just to get a week number thats ISO compliant. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim maxWeek As Integer = Globalization.ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(New Date(t_year, 12, 31))
```

Applies to .NET versions: .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET Core 3.0, .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Standard 2.1

Get Details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek.getweekofyear?view=net-6.0