# VB.NET DatetimePicker - Wrong week number

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, week-number

I have an issue with my vbnet extented datetime picker.
When the element pass to new year (2016), the week number displayed on the left is wrong.

[image: Wrong week number]

I have a "datetimepicker" which is not the default component, it was downloaded here : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17063/ExtendedDateTimePicker-control-with-week-numbers

I don't understand why the calendar pass from 53 to 2 and not 53 to 1.

Maybe one of you has the same error.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in the own article's discussion board since this isn't a default component but a third-party development.

Comment: I am trying but it's an old article.
From what i understood, what's wrong is "date format". Maybe it's not a 8601

Comment: NET's calendar is not ISO8601, but there are some calendar options to get something similar (and only 1-2 lines of code to convert or emulate). The code is not calculating the WOY, just unisng a PInvoke to get NET to do it.    If I recall, the first week of the year is one containing a Thursday.  Since 1/1/2016 is a Thursday, I think if you moved to the next month it would show Jan 1-2-3 as the first week of 2016.

Comment: OK Thanks. I have to add this directly in the control ?

Comment: Am I only one that thinks this control works perfectly? Week 53 is Dec 28,29,30,31. Week 1 is Jan 1,2,3. It is week 53/1 so there is nothing wrong with showing week 2 in next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I don't understand why the calendar pass from 53 to 2 and not 53 to 1`

It is pretty much working as expected.  The way it is counting weeks, those first 3 days of 2016 count as the first week of 2016.

Note that the control doesnt do anything calendar or display related.  It is simply changing the display *style* of the calendar window provided by Windows.  The code seen on the CP page is all there is and mainly it just sets a style flag to tell Windows to add the week numbers:

```
style = style | MCS_WEEKNUMBERS;
```

The MSDN entry for it indicates:

> Week 1 is defined as the first week that contains at least four days.

Since Jan 1-3 is not 4 days, it would seem that there is either an error, a different calendar being used or MSDN is out of date.

---

From comments:

`From what i understood, what's wrong is "date format". Maybe it's not a 8601`

No, it is more than that:  ISO8601 is a **different calendar** which neither Windows nor NET implements.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) notes:

> The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year (and, hence, always contains 4 January). ISO week year numbering therefore slightly deviates from the Gregorian for some days close to 1 January.

This is what you see in the calendar drop down.

**Alternative**

But the ISO8601 Week Of Year is easy to calculate:

Start with the code for `GetISOWeekOfYear()` from [my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791320/1070452).  You can use that to display the ISO8601 week of year for the selected date in a label or something next to the DTP.

Print the first and last week numbers for 2011 To 2021:

```
Dim cal As Calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar
For n As Int32 = 2011 To 2017       '2021
    dt = New DateTime(n, 12, 21)
    Console.WriteLine(" ***** {0} *****", n)
    For j = 0 To 3
        Dim NetWk = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, firstD)
        Console.WriteLine("Invariant Date: {0} ISO #:{1:00}  NET #:{2:00}",
                          dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), GetISOWeekOfYear(dt), NetWk)
        dt = dt.AddDays(7)
    Next
Next
```

The result for 2015/2016 portion:

> ***** 2015 *****
>   Invariant Date: 12/21/2015 ISO #:52  NET #:52
>   Invariant Date: 12/28/2015 ISO #:53  NET #:53
>   Invariant Date: 01/04/2016 ISO #:01  NET #:02
>   Invariant Date: 01/11/2016 ISO #:02  NET #:03
>   ***** 2016 *****
>   Invariant Date: 12/21/2016 ISO #:51  NET #:52
>   Invariant Date: 12/28/2016 ISO #:52  NET #:53
>   Invariant Date: 01/04/2017 ISO #:01  NET #:01
>   Invariant Date: 01/11/2017 ISO #:02  NET #:02

Unless you are willing to write your own control from scratch or license one which can be set to a different calendar (**and** has a definition for ISO8601), that may be the best you can do.

**The Bottomline:** The Week number is not wrong.  It using a different calendar than you expect/want.

---

References:

- [Get or convert NET GetWeekOfYear()  to ISO week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27744923/1070452)
- MSDN: [Month Calendar Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760919(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [DateTimePicker in Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs,ba0fcd18a90a3a79)

Comment: You should use ISO date format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) on SO to avoid any regional confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The control is working fine.

When the year changes over the final few days of the year are in week 53 - but it's not a full week. Similarly the first few days of the year are in week 1, but the control takes the system's "first day of the week" setting to determine when week 2 begins - so it is possible for the first week of the year to have any where from 1 to 7 days in it.

This means that the image you've shown is showing Week 53 because you're in December and Week 2 because the 2nd week of January does start on the 4th.

If you navigate to January it would display week 1 for the row starting on December 28.

The bottom-line is that the first week in January only has 3 days in it.

This is just the normal and correct behaviour of this control.